# In Python, how do I check a string to see if any combinations of another string are in it?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, parsing, nodes

I have a 170 000 list of words and I am writing an algorithms using a graph for each word to see the longest word chain possible;

Word chain being a list of words where the i-th word is the (i − 1)st word with one extra character and the other characters are arranged in any manner

A -> AN -> CAN -> CANE

Right now I have all the words listed alphabetically like CAT = ACT

and I say add an edge when String 2 contains string 1, plus one other character

However in the case of

A-> AT -> ACT

the edge between AT and ACT isn't drawn because the C split the A and the T and my if statement only works if "AT" was found.

How do I tell python to search a string so that the order of the characters do not matter?

Comment: Do you care about duplicates characters in the string? Like example when comparing caat and act.

Comment: You can try sorting the letters alphabetically.

Comment: If order does not matter at all, use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of a string.  You can then take multiset intersections.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a set of the two strings:

```
set1 = set(string1)
set2 = set(string2)
```

And then see if `string1` contains everything that's in `string2`

```
set1.issubset(set2) # => returns True if set2 contains everything from set1
```

Comment: i love that i use sets all day in python and never thought to set a string.  nice.

Comment: Please note this would match `CAAT` to `ACT` , not sure if they should be matched or not.

Comment: I suggested this exact approach in the OP's previous duplicate question, and was correctly informed that it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and convert both strings into it (it would count the letters in the string) , and then you can compare that for equality. Example -

```
s1 = 'ACT'
s2 = 'CAT'
from collections import Counter
if Counter(s1) == Counter(s2):
    #Do stuff
```

Demo -

```
>>> s1 = 'ACT'
>>> s2 = 'CAT'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(s1) == Counter(s2)
True
```

---

If you want to check if one string is contained in the other without caring about order, you can use `any()` built-in function as below -

```
s1 = 'AXCT'
s2 = 'CAT'
A = Counter(s1)
B = Counter(s2)
if not any(count > A.get(b, 0) for b,count in B):
    #Do stuff.
```

Or you can also do the following (as indicated by [@Kevin in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115405/in-python-how-do-i-check-a-string-to-see-if-any-combinations-of-another-string/33115430#comment54045518_33115430)) -

```
s1 = 'AXCT'
s2 = 'CAT'
A = Counter(s1)
B = Counter(s2)
if (B & A) == B:
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: May also want to demonstrate how to check for subsets using `&` (i.e. `A & B == A`).

Comment: Funny, it works for me.  Try `Counter('ACT') & Counter('ACTE') == Counter('ACT')`; I get True in 3.4.3.

Comment: @Kevin Oh yes, `A` being the subset.

Comment: Would like the downvoter to explain what is wrong with the answer, only that way I can fix the answer.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: This should work in Python 2.6 + (so both 2.7 as well as 3.x)

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = 'A'
str2 = 'T'
searchstring = 'ACT'

if str1 in searchstring and str2 in searchstring:
    print('it matched')


# bigger example

str1 = 'AT'
searchstring = 'ACT'
matches = [a for a in str1 if a in searchstring]
if len(matches) == len(searchstring):
    print('it matched')
```

Comment: Constructing `matches` is quadratic in string length, assuming both strings have similar lengths.  The other answers are more performant.

Comment: not gonna get any argument from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the longer string into a regular expression and then match it. A simple way is to make all the characters optional, having first checked that the target string is one character longer:

```
def can_reach(frm, to):
  if len(to) != len(frm) + 1: return False
  if not re.fullmatch(re.sub(r'(.)', r'\1?', to), frm): return False
  return True
```

If you don't have Python 3.4, then use an explicit `$` anchor:

```
def can_reach(frm, to):
  if len(to) != len(frm) + 1: return False
  if not re.match(re.sub(r'(.)', r'\1?', to) + '$', frm): return False
  return True
```